# ActionScript Voice Recognition Library

Tags: flash, actionscript, voice-recognition

I'm after a Voice Recognition Library in ActionScript.

I need to the software to be able to respond to simple english responses only. Yes & No type of responses.

Comment: by default, not that I know of, but you should be able to patch something up with AIR and a commandline tool talking to each other

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you looked into the poorly named [Voice Gesture](http://www.bytearray.org/?p=1151)?

Comment: Looks like a reasonable starting point, I'll wait to see if anyone knows of others.

Comment: Hi Dale Fraser, i need this voice recognition library now. could you please share that library. the link which Sam told was broken now. couldn't get source from there. I hope i will get a good response from you. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I attended the session in which Didier Braun demonstrated Voice Gesture.  The basic idea is that you turn the voice recognition problem into an image recognition problem.  The demonstration here: http://vimeo.com/8203323

From flash 10.1, you can have low level access to the microphone data which allows a developer to create an audio spectrogram.

While there are many server-side solutions to this problem, there aren't that many client-side ones, unfortunately.